# MySQLConnection ERROR: Access denied for user 'rnd-admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, terminal, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to mysql database on remote server via ssh tunnel.
When the connection with server is established, my script fails with mysql error:

```
py.warnings - WARNING - /home/artur/Exposit/Projects/dataset-collector/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
  m.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())

py.warnings - WARNING - /home/artur/Exposit/Projects/dataset-collector/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:96: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
  self.curve, Q_S_bytes

py.warnings - WARNING - /home/artur/Exposit/Projects/dataset-collector/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:111: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
  hm.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())

root - ERROR - 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rnd-admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'rnd-admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

**Note:**
When I'm connecting to the database from terminal with the same credits using `mysql -u rnd-admin -p` then everything is fine, no errors detected, and mysql **cli** is opened.

```
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                ('myhost', 22),
                ssh_username="root",
                ssh_password="passwd",
                remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as tunnel:
            if tunnel.is_active:
                db_config = read_db_config()
                conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)

                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()

                conn.commit()
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
```

**config.ini**

```
[mysql]
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
database=db-name
user=rnd-admin
password=pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue **by removing** `3306` mysql default port from config.ini and manually feeding `port=tunnel.local_bind_port` into **MySQLConnection** constructor.

```
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config, port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
```

Comment: I was about to say you weren't using the SSHTunnelForwarder's port at all, but you figured it out. :) I would also recommend ensuring the `host` is always `127.0.0.1` (as that's where the tunnel binds): `db_config = read_db_config(); db_config.update(host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port)`